# Get Flutter BLoC Current State - Flutter unit test

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Is possible to get current state in the unit test code base

Test Code

```
group('registerWithFacebookEvent', () {
    const response =
        RegisterUser(name: "Dolapo Olakanmi", message: "Successful");
    test(
        'should validate emit sequence when registerWithFacebook usecase is successful',
        () async {
      when(registerUserWithFacebook(const NoParam()))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(response));

      const expected = [Success(response: response)];
      expectLater(bloc.stream, emitsInOrder(expected));
      bloc.add(RegisterUserWithFacebookEvent());
      expect(bloc.state, expected.first);
    });
  });
```

Prod Code

```
if (event is RegisterUserWithFacebookEvent) {
   final failureOrSuccess = await registerUserWithFacebook(const NoParam());
   emit(failureOrSuccess.fold(
     (l) => throw UnimplementedError(), (r) => Success(response: r)));
}
```

The test fails because the line `expect(bloc.state, expected.first)` fails and the reason is the bloc.state return the initial state which is in my case:

```
Expected: Success:<Success()>
  Actual: RegisterUserInitial:<RegisterUserInitial()>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a quick first look it looks like you are missing an `await` before your `expectLater` inside of the`async` `test` callback function.

Also put the `expectLater` below your `bloc.add` and also include the previous states (like init, registration, loading, etc) in the expected state list, because it is the list of all states that are emitted from the bloc.

So any emitted states from the bloc should be included inside of the `expected` list (just not the `initialState` param of the bloc constructor).

So similar to the following:

```dart
group('registerWithFacebookEvent', () {
    const response =
        RegisterUser(name: "Dolapo Olakanmi", message: "Successful");
    test(
        'should validate emit sequence when registerWithFacebook usecase is successful',
        () async {
      when(registerUserWithFacebook(const NoParam()))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(response));

      const expected = [..., RegisterUserInitial(), ..., Success(response: response)];
      final Future<void> matcher = expectLater(bloc.stream, emitsInOrder(expected));
      bloc.add(RegisterUserWithFacebookEvent());
      await matcher;
      expect(bloc.state, expected.last);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @Niko for your answer it was helpful.
I have some questions though, Why do we have to make the `group` callback `async`?
And also when I followed your solution It passes regardless of the `expected` state.
What I have done currently is follow your solution but did not make the `group` callback `async` and it works fine. Although, the initialState was not part of the state stream that is `expected=[RegisterUserInitial(),...,..]`

Comment: Oh, sorry, i should have worded that a bit better: 

The `initialState` param of the bloc constructor should not be part of the expected states, only the states that are emitted (including any init, or registration states from before). 

And for the async of the outer `group` function:  only the inner `test` function callback needs to be async, which it already was. I just didn't see the inner method when reading the code the first time. 

I adjusted my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: And i forgot that the matcher from the `expectLater` has to be created before the adding of events, because otherwise it does not receive the events. 

So you have to store the future before adding the events and await it after adding the events (like the `matcher` from my code snippet above), because otherwise it would not wait for the bloc to handle the added events.

Comment: Thanks @Niko, It works as expected.